# Why did this command make my Ubuntu more awesome than before?

Tags: command-line

After running Ubuntu for months and liking it, I for the first time wanted to use headphones and was trying to get them to work so I ran the code in step 1 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

-- the result was an improvement in performance, resolution, and audio.. a vast improvement. What does that suggest about what was wrong with my settings before if running this improved system performance, graphics, and my audio problem?

The command is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa; sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

Comment: Upgrading your sound driver to a pre-release development version may have fixed a bug with your system. It may however for other people break things - so update to development drivers with caution.

Comment: It also seemed to do something with my kernel, something called gdm.. it was more than just the driver. But I thought it was legit since it was ubuntu wiki

Comment: @the_misfit Anyone can add things to the Ubuntu wiki. Be careful on that.

Comment: well all's well that ends well!